# Android Noob, Layout not working

Tags: android

Literally the most basic app going on, just learning.  I created a new XML file for a new layout, added some stuff, and I changed my `setContentView()` in MainActivity to match and I'm having trouble getting it working.  Here's my code thus far.

My onCreate():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_layout);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

and my XML new_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Legit just attempting to get it to run.

Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidsdk.demo/com.example.androidsdk.demo.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f07003c (com.example.androidsdk.demo:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{4267dc90 #0 id=0x7f07003c}
```

EDIT:

[image]

Thank you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you dont have a placeholder for your fragment. You would have to place your fragment in a view to render it.